# Accessing the gyro in the wiimotion plus using Brian Peek's Wiimotelib 1.8 beta

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wii, wiimote

I am sort of confused on how to access gyroscope data from the wiimotion plus using the wiimote lib beta 1.8. I know for the accelerometer you would do something like this:

```
Wiimote.WiimoteState.AccelState.Values.X;
```

For the wiimotion plus, I first need to initialise it by:

```
Wiimote.InitializeMotionPlus();
```

After that, I am unsure on how to access the gyro values.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a stupid mistake. This is how it is done:

```
double x = Wiimote.WiimoteState.MotionPlusState.Values.X;
```